# C# BOT Framework - PromptDialog Bot Account

Tags: c#, botframework

i've another strange question on BOT Framework and Bot Account.

View image.
[image]

Why in simple welcome message bot answer with my custom bot account,

`new ChannelAccount(id: "test.id", name: "testBot");`

but in

`[Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs] PromptDialog.Choice`

the **from name and id** is different?

My example code is:

```
    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;

        message.From = new ChannelAccount(id: "id-bot", name: "BotName");

        PromptDialog.Choice(context, this.OnOptionSelected, new List<string>() { FlightsOption, HotelsOption }, "Are you looking for a flight or a hotel?", "Not a valid option", 3);
    }
```

My questions are:

- It's possible custom PromptDialog.Choice From Name and Id?
- It's possible set bot account globally (for any reply message)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your screenshot, it looks like you're running your bot locally from Visual Studio and then using the Bot Channel Emulator tool to test your bot.

The bot's actual name is automatically set for you when you have deployed your bot into a real environment (not your dev), based what you have registered in the [Bot Framework Portal](https://dev.botframework.com). In dev, when using the emulator, it's simply always displayed as "Bot".

So don't bother trying to set your bot's name in code as you are doing now because it's unnecessary. And as a result, there is no need for you to customise `PromptDialog.Choice` either.